# undefined reference while overloading cout

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have defined a point class using dev c++. then I tried to overload cout for this class.
while not using it i get no error. but when i use it in main it gives me this error:

```
[Linker error] C:\Users\Mohammad\Desktop\AP-New folder\point/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Point const&)'
```

//point.h

```
    class Point{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
public:

    //constructors:
    Point()
    {
    x=0;
    y=0;
    z=0;
    }
    Point(double xx,double yy,double zz){x=xx; y=yy; z=zz;}

    //get:
    double get_x(){return x;}
    double get_y(){return y;}       
    double get_z(){return z;}

    //set:
    void set_point(double xx, double yy, double zz){x=xx; y=yy; z=zz;}

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&,Point&);
```

};

```
    //point.cpp
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,Point &p){
        out<<"("<<p.x<<", "<<p.y<<", "<<p.z<<")\n";
        return out;
```

}

//main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "point.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

Point O;
cout<<"O"<<O;


cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The error message suggests that the code in `point.h` was actually `friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Point&);` all along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you did not make your `Point` a `const` when declaring and defining your operator. Change your declaration as follows:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Point&);
```

Also add `const` in the definition:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Point &p){
    out<<"("<<p.x<<", "<<p.y<<", "<<p.z<<")\n";
    return out;
}
```

Note that the code that you posted does not require `const`-ness of the `Point&`. Some other code made your compiler or IDE believe that an operator with a `const` is referenced. For example, using the operator like this would require a `const`

```
cout << Point(1.2, 3.4, 5.6) << endl;
```

[(demo)](http://ideone.com/YgZ8pG)

Since the snippet above creates a temporary object, passing a reference to it as a non-const is prohibited by the C++ standard.

Not directly related to this issue, but you may want to mark the three getters for individual coordinates `const` as well:

```
double get_x() const {return x;}
double get_y() const {return y;}       
double get_z() const {return z;}
```

This would let you access coordinates with getters on objects marked `const`.

Comment: it seems to be the answer

Comment: @mohammadeslahisani They talk about `const` in the conclusion part of the lesson: "Before we finish this lesson, there is one additional point that is important to make. The overloaded output operator<< `friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Point &cPoint);` is actually better written as `friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Point &cPoint);`". Whether the non-const one works or not depends on an invocation (i.e. the code you put in `main`).

Comment: without const,in eclipse ubuntu,it gives answer to my friend!

Comment: @mohammadeslahisani He's doing something else in his `main` then.

Comment: I know it's better, but not using it should not lead to an error!

Comment: @mohammadeslahisani Could you edit the question with the exact content of your `main.cpp` file?

Comment: Just add using namespace std; in Point.h. It's working with me without adding const. const has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @mohammadeslahisani The way it is written, the `const` is indeed optional ([demo](http://ideone.com/oQKkaL)).

Comment: and now it's working without const! OMG! Damn dev-c++

Comment: @CroCo OP says that adding `const` did fix the problem.

Comment: @mohammadeslahisani My guess is that you had something like this in your code: `cout << Point();`. This requires a temporary, which requires a `const` ([demo #2](http://ideone.com/YgZ8pG)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I'm talking about the C++ standards.

Comment: @CroCo And I am talking about OP's program. He had something in his code that made the non-const operator inapplicable (perhaps something like [this](http://ideone.com/YgZ8pG)).

Comment: I have put all main now! at first it raised Linked Error but now it is not. I guess the problem is dev-c++! 'cause I closed it and reopen it the problem was solved

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, the guy mentioned where he did take the code from; as a result, the problem is not from the code as he was expecting. It has something to do with his IDE or the compiler he uses which you didn't mention in your answer; however, I didn't downvote your answer.  Cheers